# Unable to pause audio in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, html5-audio

I've followed the other posts that have asked similar questions, but they have not provided a solution.

I'm not able to pause audio in my React Hook.

This is my react hook:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default (App = props => {
  const [audioStatus, changeAudioStatus] = useState(false);
  const audio = new Audio(
    "https://mcdn.podbean.com/mf/web/xm5ngf/The_Challenge_Chronicles_-_Episode_48_7ys6e.mp3"
  );
  audio.load();

  const startAudio = () => {
    audio.play();

    changeAudioStatus(true);
  };

  const pauseAudio = () => {
    console.log("here");
    audio.pause();
    changeAudioStatus(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {audioStatus ? (
        <button onClick={pauseAudio}>pause</button>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={startAudio}>start</button>
      )}
    </>
  );
```

I've also created a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-gagarin-v0vi1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [audio](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp) tag, and pass a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to react, so that it will know what element is being used.

[working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-rosalind-89qf6)

```
export default (App = props => {
  const [audioStatus, changeAudioStatus] = useState(false);
  const myRef = useRef();

  const startAudio = () => {
    myRef.current.play();

    changeAudioStatus(true);
  };

  const pauseAudio = () => {
    console.log("here");
    myRef.current.pause();
    changeAudioStatus(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <audio
        ref={myRef}
        src="https://mcdn.podbean.com/mf/web/xm5ngf/The_Challenge_Chronicles_-_Episode_48_7ys6e.mp3"
      />
      {audioStatus ? (
        <button onClick={pauseAudio}>pause</button>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={startAudio}>start</button>
      )}
    </>
  );
});
```

Comment: Saved the day K.s .... Thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'play')...any solutions?

Comment: @ShubhamSinghvi it's hard to tell without code examples. Create a question and somebody will take a look.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem as well and solved it by changing

`const audio = new Audio(...)`

to

`const [audio, setAudio] = useState( new Audio(...) )`

I believe that by putting the audio into the state we prevent React from refreshing the audio value on each rerender, and thus the reference problem is solved. I might, however, be wrong with the conclusion; please correct me if I'm wrong. In any case, this works.

Comment: Can you explain with complete code, it shows an error

Comment: Could you please specify the error if the question is still relevant? The complete code of mine is a huge mess haha, but if I knew more details about the error, I would try to solve it. My apologies for the delayed answer!

Comment: Just in case, instead of '...' there has to be a URL of the audio file like this:
const [audio, setAudio] = useState( new Audio('your-website.com/audio.wav') )

(I know you know this, but you might have been extremely tired and just copy my code to see what will happen haha)

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize the audio outside of the React component.

```
const audio = new Audio(...)

const MyComponent=(props)=>{
  const [isMusic, isMusicSet] = React.useState(false);

  const toggleMusic = () => {
    const isMusicToggle = !isMusic;
    if (isMusicToggle) {
      audio.play();
    } else {
      audio.pause();
    }
    isMusicSet(isMusicToggle);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> const audio = new Audio(...)
>
> to
>
> const [audio, setAudio] = useState( new Audio(...) )

This solution worked for me. I was able to get rid of my ref.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your audio element into useRef to retain it throughout the component lifecycle

```
  const audio = useRef(new Audio('path/to/audio/file')).current

  audio.load();

  const startAudio = () => {
    audio.play();

    changeAudioStatus(true);
  };

    const pauseAudio = () => {
    console.log("here");
    audio.pause();
    changeAudioStatus(false);
  };
```