# Unable to pause React audio

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, html5-audio, pause

```
import { useState } from "react";

function Music(){

  const [pauseToggle, setpauseToggle] = useState(false)

  const music = new Audio(require(`./Alan.mp3`));
  console.log(music);
  let isPlaying = false;

  const player = () => {
    pauseToggle ? setpauseToggle(false) : setpauseToggle(true);
    if(isPlaying){
      music.pause();
      isPlaying = false;
    }else{
      music.play();
      isPlaying = true;
    }
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={player}>{pauseToggle?"=":">"}</button>
    </div>
  )

}

export default Music;
```

I'm unable to pause the audio. IInstead it gets played twice when I try to pause.

I tried to get help from this [Unable to pause audio in Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63003690/unable-to-pause-audio-in-reactjs) but it didn't help.

Any other solution for pausing audio file?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the `music` variable should be stateful so it's retained across renders.

```
const [music] = useState(new Audio(require(`./Alan.mp3`)));
```

and `isPlaying` should probably be found by querying the Audio object (music) and/or updated by listening for play/pause state changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd simplify state to a single boolean: your audio is either playing or not, so there's no need for redundancy here. `let isPlaying = false;` isn't state, so it's not persistent across renders and doesn't do anything `pauseToggle` doesn't already achieve.

In fact, audio elements have a `.paused` property that makes the separate state boolean redundant, but for React rendering/lifecycle purposes the extra boolean is handy.

Since the audio is a side effect to the rendering, I'd make it a ref, then trigger play/pause functions based on when `playing` changes in a `useEffect`.

A bit of a bonus, but it's probably worth handling the `onended` event to set playing to false when the track ends, for starters.

```js
const {useEffect, useRef, useState} = React;

const MusicPlayer = ({url}) => {
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
  const audioRef = useRef(new Audio(url));

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = () => setPlaying(false);
    audioRef.current.addEventListener("ended", handler);
    return () => 
      audioRef.current.removeEventListener("ended", handler)
    ;
  }, [audioRef.current]);

  useEffect(() => {
    audioRef.current[playing ? "play" : "pause"]();
  }, [playing]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setPlaying(!playing)}>
        {playing ? "=" : ">"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Webern_-_Sehr_langsam.ogg";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<MusicPlayer url={url}/>);
```

```css
button {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Putting the audio into a hook helps make it reusable and keeps your parent component clean:

```js
const {useEffect, useRef, useState} = React;

const useAudio = url => {
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
  const audioRef = useRef(new Audio(url));

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = () => setPlaying(false);
    audioRef.current.addEventListener("ended", handler);
    return () => 
      audioRef.current.removeEventListener("ended", handler)
    ;
  }, [audioRef.current]);

  useEffect(() => {
    audioRef.current[playing ? "play" : "pause"]();
  }, [playing]);

  return [playing, setPlaying];
};

const MusicPlayer = ({url}) => {
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useAudio(url);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setPlaying(!playing)}>
        {playing ? "=" : ">"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Webern_-_Sehr_langsam.ogg";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<MusicPlayer url={url} />);
```

```css
button {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```